# why does internet explorer change this png file?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, png

I built a website and I have this png file which is a bordered image with drop shadow shading which looks fine in firefox, chrome, where the dropshadow is subtle and clean (just like it looks like in photoshop)

[image]

but when i view this in Internet explorer (6, 7 or 8), it shows up like this below:

[image]

where the drop shadow shows up as all black (no fading), and disjointed

again, this is just a pure image in an html page (not javascript drop shadow script or CSS)

does anyone have a suggestion on why png image would show up different on Internet Explorer.

Comment: I know of at least IE 6, which doesn't render PNG transparency. Haven't tested in the others. Google `ie PNG fix`, or use [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fixed it with a combination of things:

1. This css:

   ```
   img {  
   background: transparent;

   -ms-filter:   "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */

   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);         /* IE6 & 7 */
   zoom: 1;
   }
   ```
2. Setting clearType = false in jquery cycle:

   ```
   $(function () {
      $('#s1').cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 1500, cleartype: false, timeout: 4500 });
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance re-scaling the image by `<img />` tag? If so, you can add

```
img {
   -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

to your CSS to force IE to use bicubic interpolation on the images. That may solve it.

Answer (score -3):

File transparency with .png files are not fully supported in IE versions 6,7,8 and it is a known bug.  I believe the issue is fixed in IE9.

A good work around is use of the AlphaImageLoader filter that works in all versions of IE.
Supporting documentation and an example work around that I have used in the past with success:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294714.

Another work around is to convert the .png to a transparent .gif file.

Comment: That is only true for IE6, IE7 brought 24-bit alpha trasnparent PNG support.

Comment: Support was introduced for IE7/8 but the issue was not fully fixed until IE9.  IE7/8 still have opacity rendering issues and issues rendering gradients properly with .png files.

Comment: Well the link you put in your comment says that it's only an issue for IE6.